# Как отцентрировать блок не зная его ширины?

Tags: css

Есть шапка, но она достаточно большая. Если ей задать явно ширину и отцентрировать то при разрешение 1024 появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки что естественно нам не подходит. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную проблему? То есть главной целью является отцентрировать шапку но таким образом чтобы если разрешение будет 1024 то не появлялась бы горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. А так в принципе ширину явно указать то и можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ширину задайте через `max-width`, а отцентруйте через `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: вы наверное ошиблись немного. с помощью max-width получилось. Спасибо вам большое при большое.

Comment: да, действительно ошибся, исправил. Пожалуйста )

Answer (score 0):

Не привязывайтесь к пикселям. Используйте проценты.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/dobby007/dhrwx/).

Comment: не, это не подходит. Во всяком случае спасибо на отзыв.

Answer (score 0):

Родителю text-align:center;блоку-inline-block